# Powershell with "array dimensions exceeded supported range" error close to 1GB file size

Tags: powershell, array, out-of-memory

I have a simple Powershell script example below:

```
$dpath = "D:\Fill"
$mask="000000"
$sizefile = 1GB
$numfiles = 10

#file mask will be "file_000000 " = 12 chars total
$fillsize = [int]($sizefile/12)

For ($fnum=0; $fnum -lt $numfiles; $fnum++) {

    # mask filename
    $fname="$mask$fnum"
    $fnamelen=$fname.Length
    $fname=$fname.Substring($fnamelen -6)
    $fname="FILE_$fname"

    Write-Host "Generating file '$fname`.txt' $($fillsize*12) bytes / $numfiles files..."
    Write-Output $("$fname "*$fillsize) | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -FilePath "$dpath\$fname`.txt" -Force

}
```

Basically writing a repeating character set to a text file. This works for anything slightly under 1GB, but 1GB throws an error: "array dimensions exceeded supported range". It can get up to 1073741784 bytes without issue, but it can't get to the full 1073741824 bytes.

Is there any way to circumvent this?

It's not a huge deal as I don't *need* it to be exactly 1GB but if there is a simple fix it would be nice to implement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a built-in limitation.

Found:
*The Memory restrictions aside, Strings cannot have more than 2^30 (1,073,741,824) characters, since a 2GB limit is imposed by the Microsoft CLR (Common Language Runtime).*

A fix I can see would be to calculate the number of extra characters you need, make a .txt file of them, and simply append this text file to the big one you're building?

Or to use another function/loop to build the file, but sorry can't help you on this (too few Powershell knowledge).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond. I read about a 2GB restriction, but this is 1GB, so not sure why it isn't 2GB. But seems like a restriction nonetheless. I could probably do some simple calculation to determine the last remaining characters as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess because a char takes 2 bytes in memory at least, allowing the string to be unicode... @HTWingNut

Comment: @Sylvain - You don’t sound confident that a character taking 2 bytes is definitely the answer. You should provide more details and a full detailed explanation for the author. The SO answer which you cut and pasted that explanation is also NOT entirely accurate.

Comment: So a more detailed explanation, yes, if you were writing 1073741824 characters each character would take 2 bytes and you would exceed the maximum array size by several bytes 2,147,483,648 vs 2,147,483,591; but the author said they were writing 1073741824 bytes. This question belongs on SO, and it apparently was on SO, before it was deleted by the author. A shame it was deleted on SO, I might have answered it on SO. One doesn’t need a vast amount of PowerShell knowledge to answer this question properly, with documentation, and a detailed full explanation.

Comment: Sorry @Ramhound. Since ZX81 (and before on Bull Mitra 15) I acquired a vast knowledge but few on specific domains. I'm definitely not a teacher. I'm also working quasi permanently, and can't spend much time to do the fine and didactic answer - that now I think SE is dedicated to. I'll think at this, and at my minuscule presence here.
Ah and I've almost zero knowledge on Powershell. And I'd be happy to delete my answer if someone gives a more educated one, here and everywhere.

Comment: @Sylvain - Focus on your domain knowledge if your unable to research a topic well enough to fully explain it, what’s not helpful, is answers that don’t contain some degree of domain knowledge. Your lack of willingness to improve your answers is troubling. I have no idea what “ZX81” is reference to. I have little to no direct PowerShell knowledge but a vast amount of .NET knowledge.

Comment: @Sylvain - Hesitant to answer a question that should be on Stack Overflow, and probably would be on SO, if the author didn’t delete it.

Comment: ZX81 had 1 KiloB memory.
It's not I've a "lack of willingness" to improve my answer; it's just I'm not going to start learning Powershell just to help an user, even 100 of them: it's another job then the one(s) I already have.
I've no domain knowledge apart computer and computers.
But I think you could answer properly (SO or SU, who cares, it's now here) after having downvoted me.

Comment: I absolutely have no idea what or who “ZX81” and “Bull Mitra 15” is

Comment: Thank you, it didn't dawn on me that each character would require 2 bytes. I do have it encoded as ASCII in the output, but in memory it may require 2. Seems like a valid point. Regardless, it is a limitation and will just live with it. It's for nothing important, and doesn't need additional investigation at least not for my use. I was just wondering if I was missing something basic (I'm not a programmer, Jim). If you want to leave an answer I'll gladly mark it as accepted.